# Cannot read property 'AllowOverride' of null for Boolean field

Tags: arraylist, angular-material, angular7

I have response above like 
[image]

i need to frame that

```
const masterSettingResponse = {
            masterSMS: {
                allowOverRide: setting.MasterSMS.AllowUserOverride,
                smsEnabled: setting.MasterSMS.SMSEnabled,
                smsUrl: setting.MasterSMS.SMSURL,
                accessToken: setting.MasterSMS.AccesToken,
                smsLogUrl: setting.MasterSMS.SMSLogUrl,
                clientId: setting.MasterSMS.ClientId,
            },
            masterEmail: {
                allowOverRide: setting.MasterEmail.AllowOverride,
                emailEnabled: setting.MasterEmail.EmailEnabled,
                emailLogUrl: setting.MasterEmail.EmailLogUrl,
                accessToken: setting.MasterEmail.AccessToken,
                emailUrl: setting.MasterEmail.EmailUrl,
                clientId: setting.MasterEmail.ClientId,
            },
            masterGeneralSetting: {
                isActive: setting.MasterGeneralSetting.IsActive,
                portalSessionTimeout: setting.MasterGeneralSetting.PortalSessionTimeout,
                appSessionTimeout: setting.MasterGeneralSetting.AppSessionTimeout,
            },
        };

        return masterSettingResponse;
```

While coming to MasterEmail I am getting an 'AllowOverride' Null Exception.
But, it is boolean property. If the data is not available I need to show 'masterEmail' as null. How do I overcome the Exception?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a property from a null object. Add a check for this to solve your problem.

```
const masterSettingResponse = {
            masterSMS: {
                allowOverRide: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.AllowUserOverride : null),
                smsEnabled: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.SMSEnabled : null),
                smsUrl: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.SMSURL : null),
                accessToken: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.AccesToken : null),
                smsLogUrl: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.SMSLogUrl : null),
                clientId: (setting.MasterSMS ? setting.MasterSMS.ClientId : null),
            },
            masterEmail: {
                allowOverRide: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.AllowOverride : null),
                emailEnabled: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.EmailEnabled : null),
                emailLogUrl: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.EmailLogUrl : null),
                accessToken: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.AccessToken : null),
                emailUrl: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.EmailUrl : null),
                clientId: (setting.MasterEmail ? setting.MasterEmail.ClientId : null),
            },
            masterGeneralSetting: {
                isActive: (setting.MasterGeneralSetting ? setting.MasterGeneralSetting.IsActive : null),
                portalSessionTimeout: (setting.MasterGeneralSetting ? setting.MasterGeneralSetting.PortalSessionTimeout : null),
                appSessionTimeout: (setting.MasterGeneralSetting ? setting.MasterGeneralSetting.AppSessionTimeout : null),
            },
        };
```